# Not able to understand where the extra time is getting added when a API is completed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-eks, latency

I am experiencing following weird behaviour -

**From client(browser) a API call is made to server to fetch user details. The time required by this API to complete is around 650 ms. But in browser it is showing that the request got completed in 3 secs (this time varies from 1.5 sec to 5 secs).**

I want to figure out where this extra time is getting added. I am not able to currently troubleshoot this problem. I know that there is some delay added due to network latency considering the client location and server location, but this delay is expected to be around 150 to 250 ms. But the difference in time that I am observing is too much.

Following are more details about the infrastructure -

**Client (Browser) Location - Mumbai, India**

**Server Location - North Virginia (AWS Cloud)**

On the backend we have **micro services** and these are deployed on **AWS cluster** and we are using **Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service**. Our architecture looks like following -

**ASW Load Balancer --> INGRESS --> NGINX -->  API GATEWAY (Micro services)**

I need to understand where this extra time is getting added, **is it really network latency** or **there is some issue happening in the above architecture and if yes at which layer the delay might be getting added**.

Comment: You expect 150 to 250 ms of delay from Mumbai to North Virginia? That's 13,000 km and a ton of hops. Your expectations are unreasonable. Use AWS Asia Pacific (Mumbai) Region.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for the response. I have set those expectation based on the latency data I have seen. Following website provides AWS  latency grid between different regions. 
https://www.cloudping.co/grid
Here the latency that is mentioned is around 206 ms.

Comment: You can 100% trust random sites on the Internet. Including this one. Anyway, I'll assume you're looking at their default view of 50th percentile. Do you understand what a percentile is? Use your local region.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes I understand what percentile is but can you please help me in understanding more about it. I just want to make sure the lag that I am experiencing is 100 % due to network hops and there is no delay getting added in the application layers that we have.

Comment: You could launch a Windows EC2 instance in `us-east-1` and run a browser to measure the speed from there. That would remove the network latency and you could see how much time is being consumed 'within' the stack.

Comment: There are a few components in your stack (LB, Ingress, Nginx, etc.). In which of the components are you getting the 650ms for the API request?